# NOT EXISTS on empty table returning false

Tags: mysql, subquery, not-exists

I have a SELECT query across 2 tables that isn't returning any results and I have no idea why it isn't. This is the query that doesn't return any rows:

```
SELECT b.name, b.description, b.badge_id 
FROM badges AS b 
WHERE b.type = 'have' AND b.brand_id = 'zTR7wH5FMl' AND ISNULL(b.series_id) AND b.amount <= 89 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT date_earned 
                FROM users_badges AS ub 
                WHERE ub.user_id = 'fMcBBx' AND ub.badge_id = b.badge_id)
```

If I just take off the AND NOT EXISTS clause at the end to check that they haven't already earned the badge I get these results back:

```
name            description                                             badge_id
Baker's Dozen   Add 13 items to your Johnny Cupcakes shelf.             sdfKHJkun7
Cupcaker        Have 82 items on your Johnny Cupcakes shelf.            4MeoheBdik
Freshly Baked   Have your first item on your Johnny Cupcakes shelf...   kdJGH98NdI
```

Which is exactly what I expect to get. The AND NOT EXISTS check is the only difference. There is no data in the users_badges table yet, so I don't see why it would be returning false. It seems to me that it would be incapable of returning false. Why would it be invalidating the entire query?

Comment: replace "date_earned" with * in the EXISTS selection...

Comment: SQL doesn't actually check the SELECT condition in EXISTS if I recall correctly, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a row to the table seems to have solved it. I guess if the table is empty SQL doesn't even check the EXISTS condition and always returns false because there is no way the row could exist in the table.

Comment: This sounds like a serious bug. Yes, MySQL will sometimes show `no matching row in const table` or `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables` in the EXPLAIN output, for a query with a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` when the table in the subquery is empty. (At least, with InnoDB it does). But that doesn't at all explain why MySQL returns an incorrect result. (An empty table isn't an excuse for MySQL to return incorrect results.)

Comment: I noticed that if I deleted the extra row to leave the table empty again, it still returned correctly. It was only returning incorrectly before the table had ever had any data inserted into it. If you copy the title of the question into google the 3rd or 4th result is a bug report in which the mysql dev team says that it isn't a bug. I don't see why they say that though.

Comment: It is a SERIOUS DEFECT. I see the bug report, it was closed because of a flaw in the way the bug was reported, not because the behavior of MySQL is correct. I checked the documentation, only reference I find to the EXISTS predicate is in 13.2.9.6 `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html`. The specification is pretty slim. "If sq returns a row, then EXISTS sq is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS sq is FALSE". So technically, the spec doesn't prohibit "NOT EXISTS sq is FALSE" when no rows are returned. If the spec allows it, then it's SERIOUS DEFECT in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `NOT EXISTS` with a `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT    b.name, b.description, b.badge_id 
FROM      badges b 
LEFT JOIN user_badges ub ON b.badge_id = ub.badge_id AND ub.user_id = 'fMcBBx'
WHERE     b.type = 'have' AND 
          b.brand_id = 'zTR7wH5FMl' AND 
          b.amount <= 89 AND
          b.series_id IS NULL AND 
          ub.badge_id IS NULL
```